# How to get User PC DNS avoiding Proxy in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, flash, dns

I have an application in ASP.NET with C#. I want to get client PC IP/Subnet/DNS. If user use any proxy server, I need to avoid them. I need actual client information. I have no problem with silverlight or similar technologies.

Please help.

Comment: Why not simply hard-code it to 192.168.0.3 ? Would not be much better than this even if you are able to get it...

Comment: What you ask is not possible. That information is not exposed in any reliable way through proxies and NAT.